# Percentage of users with gold badges

Tags: discussion, badges, data-dump, data-analysis

What percentage of users possess at least one gold badge?  Just curious.

Comment: Good question. I just noticed that the data dump doesn't include the badge colours, so they would have to be hand-coded from the /badges/ page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My results based on Aug 6 data dump, with catch one small catch: it does not include tag-specific badges (like [java gold](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/44/java)).  I am working on that now, but it requires a bit of massaging.

- 610 users have gold
- 866 gold badges
- 60556 users have at least one badge
- 103659 users total
- 20428 users have reputation > 100

So, that gives us a couple of statistics like

- 1.01% of users with at least one badge have a gold
- 0.59% of all users have a gold
- 2.99% of users with with reputation > 100 have gold

Comment: Is this for SO only or for all the sites?

Comment: The public data dumps only over SO, to date.

Comment: Any chance this could be run again to see no of golds we have now?

Answer (score 4):

At the moment of this writing, SO has 988 owners of gold badges, counted from the [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) manually. The [users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=2528) shows 2527*35 + 11 = 88456 users. Therefore 998/88456 * 100 = 1.1169 % of the user at the time of writing have a gold badge. (These are not distinct users, so there are less people awarded, this is an upper boundary).

There is a way to calculate this, [searching](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/) for all badges and the number of users. For a hint:

```
select Count(distinct userid) from badges 
  where name = "famous question" or name = "fanatic" ...
select Count(*) from users
```

Comment: Do you mean *"988 gold badges, but not unique owners of gold"*?  Many badges can be awarded more than once.

Comment: Gah! Use `in`, not `or`. `or` is rarely if ever optimized in SQL. `where name in ('famous question', 'fanatic', ...)`. Often times, `in` is made into a hash table for SQL to run a hash join against. `or`s are never given this awesomely special treatment. Each value of the `or` is evaluated for every row. And that makes me a sad panda.